# Angular2 how to clear the input value on submit without passing dom element

Tags: input, angular

I've read that it is not good practice to pass the dom element so I come up with such view:

```
         <div>
            <input #message placeholder="message" (keyup.enter)="add(message.value)" />
            <button (click)="add(message.value)">Add+</button>
            <p>
                the message is {{ message.value }}
            </p>
        </div>
```

As you can see I am passing the `message.value` to my `add` method

```
add(message: string) {
        this.message = message;
        console.log(this.message);
        this.messengerService.add(this.message);
    }
```

But how can I clear the so inside `add` method so `input #message` won't containg any text? I tried `message = null;` but it is does not work.

Comment: try this.message="" or this.message=undefined.

Comment: yeah I tried that as well

Answer (score 1):

If you extend your response with (blur)= , you can reset the input field as follows:

```
<div>
        <input #message placeholder="message (keyup.enter)="add(message.value)" (blur)="add(message.value); message.value='' " />
        <button (click)="add(message.value)">Add+</button>
        <p>
            the message is {{ message.value }}
        </p>
    </div>
```

Note added: **(blur)=add(message.value); message.value=''**

Answer (score 1):

you can use ngModel instead of #elem.value :

```
  <div>
   <input placeholder="message" [(ngModel)]="message" (keyup.enter)="add(message)"/>
      <button (click)="add(message)">Add+</button>
        <p>
           the message is {{ message }}
         </p>
  </div>
```

and then clear the input value by adding

```
  this.message = null;
```

in add function. This will work :

```
    add(message: string) {
      this.message = message;
      console.log(this.message);
      this.messengerService.add(this.message);
      this.message = null;
    }
```

your `message.value` attribute in view was not mapped to `this.message` in modal

Answer (score 1):

Why to use extra Parameter when angular provides two way data binding in the form of `[(ngModel)]`. you can use ngModel to get notified both side on view as well as in the class/controller. no need to pass extra parameter along with method call. so you can use this simplified approach here

```
<div>
   <input placeholder="message" [(ngModel)]="message" (keyup.enter)="add()"/>
      <button (click)="add(); message = null">Add+</button>
        <p>
           the message is {{ message }}
         </p>
  </div>

message: string = null;
 add() {
      console.log(this.message);
      // this.messengerService.add(this.message);
    }
```

here is working demo for the same <kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zzuqt3UNj2bKYWz46Tnp?p=preview)</kbd>

> The `ngModel` input property sets the element's value property and the `ngModelChange` output property listens for changes to the element's value. The details are specific to each kind of element and therefore the NgModel directive only works for elements, such as the input text box.